# Склонение даты в виде предложения

Tags: php, дата

Доброго времени суток. 
Существует способ вывода даты в виде предложения, но только на английском языке.
Собственно, вот сам код:

```
    function timeago($date) {
    if (empty($date)) {
        return "No date provided";
    }
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

    $now = time();
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);

    // check validity of date
    if (empty($unix_date)) {
        return "";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if ($now > $unix_date) {
        $difference = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense = "ago";
    } else {
        $difference = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense = "from now";
    }

    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }

    $difference = round($difference);

    if ($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }

    return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
}
```

Я не сильно умен в этом плане, поэтому думал, как возможно реализовать склонения, используя данный метод. Прошу помочь советами. Заранее спасибо!

**Обновление**

Ну, в результате должно быть: "1 секунду назад", "2 секунды назад", "5 секунд назад" или "1 час назад", "2 часа назад", "5 часов назад" и так далее. То есть должны соблюдаться правила склонения слов. Для этого я использую вот такую функцию:

```
        function num2word($num,$words) {

      $num=$num%100;

      if ($num>19) { $num=$num%10; }

      switch ($num) {

        case 1:  { return($words[0]); }

        case 2: case 3: case 4:  { return($words[1]); }

        default: { return($words[2]); }

      }

    }
```

Но, к сожалению, не могу понять, как ее можно применить здесь.

Answer (score 1):

```
function numRus($num, $word) {
    if ($num % 10 == 1 && $num % 100 != 11) {
       return $word[0];
    } elseif ($num % 10 >= 2 && $num % 10 <= 4 && ($num % 100 < 11 || $num % 100 > 14) {
       return $word[1];
    } else {
       return $word[2];
    }
}

$nums = array(1,2,3,4,5,12,14,182,377,1097);
$minute = array('минута', 'минуты', 'минут');

foreach ($nums as $num) {
   echo $num . ' ' . numRus($num, $minute) . ' назад<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для времени/дат можно воспользоваться сервисом http://momentjs.com

Comment: Спасибо! Решил вопрос данным скриптом.